# GTA V: Criminal Enterprises DLC

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I bought the CE for GTA online and can’t find the frigged. The helicopter that comes with it. But my bunker and club are far apart and driving back and forth around the mountain is a pain

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are talking about the [Frogger](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Frogger), that is included in the [Criminal Enterprise Starter Pack](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Criminal_Enterprise_Starter_Pack).

Just head into [Warstock Cache & Carry](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Warstock_Cache_%26_Carry) and search the Frogger. You will see that you are able to "buy it for free", just click buy and after a few minutes you will receive a notification that your vehicle was delivered to [Pegasus](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Pegasus_Lifestyle_Management).

A new contact should be added to your phone (if it wasn't already) called Pegasus. Just call them to request a Frogger delivery for GTA$100. Your heli will be marked on the map so just go and enjoy it.